# How to install Gnome Flashback DE on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, desktop-environments, gnome-classic

Please advice how to properly install Gnome Flashback DE on Ubuntu 14.04 (that comes with Unity by default). I want keep all application that was preinstalled with Unity DE: LibreOffice Writer, Calc, Impress, etc. 
Should I only run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install gnome-session-flashback
```

Should I uninstall Unity first? Or after installation of Gnome Flashback? There is no need to have two Desktop Environment installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install GNOME Flashback session and use it.

There is no need to uninstall Unity. For example GNOME Flashback in Ubuntu use unity-settings-deamon, so trying uninstall whole Unity might uninstall Flashback session too.

Comment: I think I should install `gnome-panel`, not the full `gnome-session-flashback`: is  that corrrect?

Comment: Depends on what you want... gnome-panel only will not be enough, you will not be able to select Flashback session in login screen.

Comment: I mean, gnome-panel is gnome-fallback, and only includes the metacity window manager and not Compiz, and therefore no Unity either.
If I have default ubuntu-desktop package installed, then I have installed also Unity and Compiz packages, which the fallback session would be able to use. So if I install gnome-panel I should be able to get just the fallback session?

Comment: gnome-panel package is not enough to get fallback session unless it depends on needed packages which it should not. gnome-panel just gives you panel, few applets and nothing more. Install `gnome-session-flashback`.